# What is the main influence on the current when charging a capacitance?

Tags: capacitor, charging, inrush-current, integrator

If I have some capacitance *C* that is being charged through a resistor *R*, is the amplitude of the current
peak only depending on *R* or also to some degree on *C*?
In other words, will the current change, if I only change the capacitance but not the resistor? [This source](https://www.sensata.com/calculator/precharge) describes the current peak as $$I(t=0)=\frac{V}{R}$$ when using a charging resistor. I know that the current into a capacitor is $$i_C(t)=C\frac{dv(t)}{dt}$$ So I would assume that the value of the capacitor still has an influence on the current even if a charging resistor is used.

Comment: What does "precharge" mean to you and how does it differ from "charge"?

Comment: I was thinking of a concept to limit inrush currents into capacitors (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-charge). But I guess it's not actually relevant for my question.

Comment: How good is your math? Add one more equation, KVL, and you can derive whatever you care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *is the amplitude of the current peak only depending on R or also to
> some degree on C?*

The peak amplitude of the current is dependent only on the supply voltage and the resistor. The peak amplitude only occurs at initial application of a sudden voltage change. When a sudden voltage change is applied, the capacitive reactance becomes zero leaving only the resistor and supply to define the current peak.

Here's an [example](https://www.utmel.com/tools/capacitor-energy-and-time-constant-calculator?id=37): -

[image]

On the left is the charging voltage and clearly, it doesn't instantaneously start at any value other than 0 volts (for a previously discharged capacitor). This has to mean that all the supply voltage is applied across the resistor at that first instant in time.